# How to read a special character from rtf file using C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, special-characters, rtf

I am using C# to convert RTF to XML.

When reading the rich text there are special character's that are represented by special RTF tags. Eg:  the double quote symbol `”` the rtf tag is \'d3

When ever I read this symbol I need to write "&rdquo" in xml.

**Is there any documentation that lists the RTF tags for all the special characters or is it possible to do some encoding to convert?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [RTF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140277%28v=office.10%29.aspx) and read up on the [Document Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

The article has  all the code values for the special characters (RTF Tags) list, eg:

```
\rdblquote  0xD3
```